# pyCairo Stack images

Tags: python, cairo, pycairo

I'm using pycairo to compose images.

Currently I am creating my ImageSurface from a base image and setting a Context from this Surface.

```
surface = cairo.ImageSurface.create_from_png("base.png")
ctx = cairo.Context (surface)
```

Then I can for example add text on top:

```
# draw text
ctx.select_font_face('Sans')
ctx.set_font_size(20) 
ctx.move_to(10, 90)
ctx.set_source_rgb(1.00, 0.83, 0.00)    # yellow
ctx.show_text('Hello World')
```

And finally stroking and saving

```
ctx.stroke() 
surface.write_to_png('hello_world.png') # write to file
```

Apart from text, I also need to load other images and put then on top of my base image at specific locations.

Should I create another surface from a new image and then stack the surfaces, or can I directly load the new image into the context at an specific location as I do with text?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly load images into a context. You need more surfaces.